# Allow chinese Characters in a valid email address.

Tags: ios, swift

i am looking to find a way to allow Chinese characters in an valid email.

The current code i have is :

```
fileprivate func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

How do i change the above code to allow Chinese characters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [the API Reference for `NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression), you can use the syntax `\p{UNICODE PROPERTY NAME}` to match any character with a specified [Unicode Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). If you wanted to allow both [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) and Latin characters in your email address, you could try using the "Han" Unicode property in a regular expression like the following:

```
let emailRegEx = "([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]|\\p{Han})+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Following Regex expressions are used to allow other languages.

```
(\p{L}),(\w+),(\w),
```